# how to load require.js relative paths

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have an app set up using backbone.  I'm using requirejs to get load files as different modules.  I have the following declared at the top of my app.js file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var base = require(__dirname + '/views/base.js');
var template = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/templates/sampleView.mu', 'utf8');
var SampleCollection = require(__dirname + '../collections/sample.js');
```

base and template load fine, but SampleCollection does not because it is actually located one directory up from the current directory where app.js is located.  I get this error when I run my app:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/collections/sample.js'
```

Why can't I use the "../" syntax to move up one directory? And what is the right way to do this?

Comment: I think you should be doing `'../collections/sample.js'` if it is outside then why would `__dirname` be part of that path...

Comment: I tried that and get the following error when I run grunt:  Error: cannot find module '../collections/sample.js' from 'c:\dev\test\app'

Comment: I was able to get it working.  I had been under the impression that "./" was the location of the file from which I was calling my modules.  However, "./" seems to point to the application root.  From there then I can just navigate to the file I need by moving forward.